My certificate pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC issue in Windows Server 2022
I'm trying to sign my JWT with a certificate saved as Base64 in my database, protected by a password.
My code works fine on my Windows Server 2012, but when I moved it to Windows Server 2022, it throws an exception: Invalid provider type specified.
My code .NET 4.7.2:
        //Load certificate
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

        //Make header, add signing certificate
        var header = new JwtHeader(new X509SigningCredentials(certificate));
        header.Add(JwtHeaderParameterNames.X5c, new string[] { Convert.ToBase64String(certificate.RawData) });

        //Make payload
        var payload = new JwtPayload(issuer, audience, claimes, notBefore: null, expires);

        //Make token and sign
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);

        //Serialize
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

The exception: Invalid provider type specified.
at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)                         
at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, 
Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)                         
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()                         
at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)                         
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()                         
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)                         
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()                         at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKeyStatus()                         

at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider..ctor(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures)                        
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateSignatureProvider(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean willCreateSignatures, Boolean cacheProvider)       
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.CryptoProviderFactory.CreateForSigning(SecurityKey key, String algorithm, Boolean cacheProvider)                        
 at Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens.JwtTokenUtilities.CreateEncodedSignature(String input, SigningCredentials signingCredentials)                     
 at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.WriteToken(SecurityToken token)

and my certificate :MAC: sha1, Iteration 1024
MAC length: 20, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 1024

I'm not sure why it didn't work. I ended up having to create all the JWT signing keys myself instead of using the ones provided by Microsoft, and it started working on Windows Server 2022. I'm still not fully sure why I received the 'Invalid provider type specified' error."
public static string BuildOAuth2TokenV3(Dictionary<string, string> claimesItem, DateTime expires, string apiTokenEndPoint, byte[] certificateBytes, string password)
{
    string issuer = "http://tempuri.org";
    string audience = apiTokenEndPoint;

    // Load the certificate from a PFX file
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var privateKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    var publicKey = certificate.GetRSAPublicKey();
    var header = new { alg = "RS256", typ = "JWT", x5c = new string[] { Convert.ToBase64String("xxxxx") } };

    // Create the payload
    var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in claimesItem)
    {
        payload.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }

    payload.Add("exp", new DateTimeOffset(expires).ToUnixTimeSeconds());
    payload.Add("iss", issuer);
    payload.Add("aud", audience);

    string jwt = CreateJwt(header, payload, privateKey);

    // Verify the JWT
    bool isValid = VerifyJwt(jwt, publicKey);

    return jwt;
}

// <summary>
/// CreateJwt
/// </summary>
/// <param name="header"></param>
/// <param name="payload"></param>
/// <param name="privateKey"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string CreateJwt(object header, object payload, RSA privateKey)
{
// Encode Header
var headerJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(header);
var headerBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(headerJson);
var headerBase64 = Base64UrlEncode(headerBytes);

// Encode Payload
var payloadJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);
var payloadBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payloadJson);
var payloadBase64 = Base64UrlEncode(payloadBytes);

// Create Signature
var signature = CreateSignature(headerBase64, payloadBase64, privateKey);

// Combine all parts
return $"{headerBase64}.{payloadBase64}.{signature}";
}
    
/// <summary>
/// CreateSignature
/// </summary>
/// <param name="header"></param>
/// <param name="payload"></param>
/// <param name="privateKey"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string CreateSignature(string header, string payload, RSA privateKey)
{
var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{header}.{payload}");
var signatureBytes = privateKey.SignData(messageBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
return Base64UrlEncode(signatureBytes);
}

/// <summary>
/// VerifyJwt
/// </summary>
/// <param name="jwt"></param>
/// <param name="publicKey"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool VerifyJwt(string jwt, RSA publicKey)
{
var parts = jwt.Split('.');
if (parts.Length != 3)
return false;

var header = parts[0];
var payload = parts[1];
var signature = parts[2];

var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{header}.{payload}");
var signatureBytes = Base64UrlDecode(signature);
return publicKey.VerifyData(messageBytes, signatureBytes, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}

/// <summary>
/// Base64UrlEncode
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] input)
{
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
return base64.Replace("+", "-").Replace("/", "_").Replace("=", "");
}

/// <summary>
/// Base64UrlDecode
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static byte[] Base64UrlDecode(string input)
{
var base64 = input.Replace("-", "+").Replace("_", "/");
switch (base64.Length % 4)
{
case 2:
    base64 += "==";
    break;
case 3:
    base64 += "=";
    break;
}
return Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
}

